# Why was this suggested edit approved?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

This suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3313077
If you look at the Markdown side-by-side view, then you can see two invalid edits in the code block:

1. First of all, there's an unnecessary `<div>seriously</div>` added to the code block.
2. Secondly, the word `Save` is added to the code block, but this wasn't necessary at all.

So, why is this edit approved? Am I missing something?

Comment: Robo-reviewers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, why is this edit approved? Am I missing something?

The person who suggested the edit is the OP of the question.

If you look carefully at the question, he is trying to make the answer consistent with the question. Not to say that this edit is necessary, but nor is it so wrong that we should call those who approved this edit robo-reviewers.